# How to display emoji's in web view in iOS 9?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, emoji

```
[_webView loadData:[objEventDetail.eventdesc dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]  MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

This is the HTML string

```
<p style="margin: 0px 0px 6px; color: rgb(20, 24, 35); font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19.32px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Team Unstoppable has got your back<em style="background-image:url(&quot;/rsrc.php/v2/yp/r/aeO1ik7i7-T.png&quot;); background-position:0px -5950px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:auto; display:inline-block; height:16px; vertical-align:-3px; width:16px"></em><em style="background-image:url(&quot;/rsrc.php/v2/yp/r/aeO1ik7i7-T.png&quot;); background-position:0px -5950px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:auto; display:inline-block; height:16px; vertical-align:-3px; width:16px"></em></p>

<p style="margin: 6px 0px; color: rgb(20, 24, 35); font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19.32px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">On Friday 22nd April, we invite you to Club 51 Degrees to celebrate the birthday  of one of Dancehall&#39;s heavy hitters.</p>

<p style="margin: 6px 0px; color: rgb(20, 24, 35); font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 19.32px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">All the way from Jamaica&nbsp;<em style="background-image:url(&quot;/rsrc.php/v2/yp/r/aeO1ik7i7-T.png&quot;); background-position:0px -2839px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:auto; display:inline-block; height:16px; vertical-align:-3px; width:16px"></em><em style="background-image:url(&quot;/rsrc.php/v2/yp/r/aeO1ik7i7-T.png&quot;); background-position:0px -2839px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:auto; display:inline-block; height:16px; vertical-align:-3px; width:16px"></em>CHARLY BLACK!!!!</p>

<p style="margin: 0px 0px 6px;">We got Trinidad  &amp; Jamaica  lined up +<br />
Guest artistes :<br />
-Press Kay<br />
-Pretti Kiiti<br />
-Shurwayne Winchester<br />
-5 Star Akil</p>

<p style="margin: 6px 0px;">Guest DJ -<br />
~ZJ Johnny Kool from Jamaica&#39;s Zip 103fm</p>

<p style="margin: 6px 0px;">Also on the roster for this birthday bash:</p>

<p style="margin: 6px 0px;">&bull;Custodian Int&#39;l<br />
&bull;Rapid Response<br />
&bull;Trevlyn the Voice<br />
&bull;Hollywood Sachy</p>

<p style="margin: 6px 0px;">Limited advance early bird tickets $150✔<br />
Only a few VIP booths available✔</p>

<p style="margin: 6px 0px;">Go to or contact&nbsp;<em style="background-image:url(&quot;/rsrc.php/v2/yp/r/aeO1ik7i7-T.png&quot;); background-position:0px -4590px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:auto; display:inline-block; height:16px; vertical-align:-3px; width:16px"></em>any committee member for tickets and details.</p>

<p style="margin: 6px 0px;">Dress Code In Effect: Glamorous&nbsp;<em style="background-image:url(&quot;/rsrc.php/v2/yp/r/aeO1ik7i7-T.png&quot;); background-position:0px -7225px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:auto; display:inline-block; height:16px; vertical-align:-3px; width:16px">✨</em></p>

<p style="margin: 6px 0px;">&nbsp;</p>

<p style="margin: 6px 0px;">Link up&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/nochupidness?source=feed_text&amp;story_id=10154101441998875" style="color: rgb(59, 89, 152); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;">‪#&lrm;NoChupidness‬</a></p>
```

I have successfully display text but not getting emoji's on this string.

Comment: display html string in web view,I have successfully display text but not getting emoji's on this string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966922/emoji-and-uiwebview-in-ios-5

Answer (score 0):

Don't write unicodes for smileys, it will not be displayed. I faced the same problem and what worked for me was adding emoji's from the emoji window from menu bar. when you are trying to add emoji in html file just open emoji window by going to edit>emoji&symbol and add emoji's from there. It will be displayed.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: but html text is coming from server(database),how can i add the emoji's into that string.